# Qu' est-ce que le sigle UEL signifie?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, abréviations

Tous ce que j'ai récemment appris c' est qu' on utilse ça parallélement (mais pas pareillement) au UFL (unité fourragère lait) en écrivant de la ration des animaux et que c' est bien sûr une autre unité à mesurer qqch liée au lait.

Answer (score 3):

Trouvé en 30 secondes avec l'aide de Google : [**U**nité d'**E**ncombrement **L**ait](http://dico-sciences-animales.cirad.fr/liste-mots.php?fiche=28384&def=unit%C3%A9%20d%27encombrement)